# Windows form Options for local storage(no DB)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows form application. I need to store date value it should be available after the application restart. One option is saving in a file which can be accessible and modified.I have tried embedded resource but it is read only.Is there any option for windows form application to persist such variables.

Comment: What do you want to do with your settings file? Do you want to store it for all users or one file for each user? Look at an example from microsoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397755(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: everything can be accessed and modified unless you encrypt it

Comment: you could try binary serialization with e.g. [protobuf-net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/protobuf-net) for the data to be at least less obvious

Comment: Thanks @SebastianSchulz !!

Comment: To set the property:

`Properties.Settings.Default.LastLoginDate=currenDateTime.ToString();`
`Properties.Settings.Default.Save();`
To get property:
`Properties.Settings.Default.LastLoginDate;`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a local file (xml, ini, app.config, etc...) or you can use the Windows Registry if you don't want to write it in a file.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Service based database(local db) just for saving that data.
At first store some default values and then update and retrieve when ever necessary.
It works for me.Not sure it's efficient!

Comment: You're suggesting to use an entire database to store a single date value?  I would say that is not at all efficient.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).